# Window.Top reads different result in .NET 4 to .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

We have a WPF project developed with .NET 3.5, we have converted to .NET 4, to benefit from new features, but, our main window's `top` & `left` properties get different results than they did in .NET 3.5

In 3.5: `top` reads -7, in 4.0: it reads 0 ( when we start the app )

but, if we run the following code, it will read normally as before:

```
(this as Window).WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
(this as Window).WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I assume you mean a maximized window. If you maximize a window, the border will be outside the normal bounds of the screen and thus Top and Left have negative values. It could be that .NET 4 changed this to be zero even if maximized, while .NET 3.5 doesn't.

- SeriTools

Comment: as I stated, after we execute the code:
(this as Window).WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
(this as Window).WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;

the window will be maximized, and then, top reads -7 again like it did at .NET 3.5
if you are right, then, it will keep reading zero even after executing the above code!

Comment: Well, then i recommend you to use WinAPI for getting these values. It will always return the border thickness (in this case -7) in case of maximized windows. ;)